# How to configure wordpress dev, major, minor updates configuration

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I read https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates and few documents Regarding Configuring Automatic Updates

Elegant Themes article says that

```
add_filter('allow_dev_auto_core_updates', '__return_false');
```

This will enable all core updates. However, some people may not want nightly builds and development updates **included–just the important security**, minor and major changes. To disable those add the following bit of code to your functions.php file and you’re all set.

We already decided to go with

```
// Enable major version updates:
add_filter('allow_major_auto_core_updates', '__return_true');

// Disable minor updates
add_filter('allow_minor_auto_core_updates', '__return_true');

/* Enable Plugin Auto Update */
add_filter('auto_update_plugin', '__return_true');

/* Enable Theme Auto Update */
/* Active Theme get_update_theme sadece adminler icin calistigi icin bunu etkileyemecektir. */
add_filter('auto_update_theme', '__return_true');

// Enable Translation Updates
add_filter('auto_update_translation', '__return_true');
```

Would you please let us know,
**for a production site**.

1 - What is the true way to go with allow_dev_auto_core_updates ?

2 - Are there any problem to go with minor and major updates enabled?

As we understand,

enabled : we can have problem with new wordpress codes with our current codes so site can go down by code conflicts.

disabled : we can have problem with old wordpress codes there may be important security hole and there will be possible hack? till minor or major update?

Comment: What would be more of a ballache? Fixing a probably minor if any bug or a hacked out site? Which would cost you more in time/money/reputation if that situation happened? Have a staging environment set to auto-update and production not. That way you will know because your staging environment goes down then make a decision on production once you have fixed the staging issues. Really, you should be following the changelogs of the libraries you use so that you can make an educated guess as to whether or not something craps out from an update.

Comment: @ggdx this is the question. My understandings true? If so we should have it enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is "no it is not good idea to have nightly builds automatically enabled"

Here are some explanations what they are.
How they should be

Enable enable automatic updates for development versions.
Should be definitely false for production site.

```
add_filter('allow_dev_auto_core_updates', '__return_false');
```

Automatically update to major releases (e.g., 4.0, 4.1, 5.0, 5.1, 6.0, 6.1)

All wordpress major releases are named in honor of jazz musicians (WordPress 4.9 “Tipton”, WordPress 5.0 “Bebo”)
Shoud be false also, because new features of wordpress can broke your site.

```
add_filter('allow_major_auto_core_updates', '__return_false');
```

Automatically update to minor releases (e.g., 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3)
No problem to go with. Only necessary changes.

```
add_filter('allow_minor_auto_core_updates', '__return_true');
```

Enable Plugin Auto Update

```
add_filter('auto_update_plugin', '__return_true');
```